# How can I change numbers automatically in a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html

Well, I want to use 3 numbers in a paragraph, Like number **"1"** will change to number **"2"** and wait for **2 seconds** and then it changes to number **"3"** and again. **(2 seconds delay for each time change)**, it should be automatically done and I know nothing about javascript so please tell me how to write it in html.
Thanks in advance

Comment: use `setInterval()` to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, edited to work with predefined numbers,
you can add as much numbers as you want in the array

```js
var p = document.querySelector("p"),
  n = [15, 45, 79],
  x = 1;
  
p.innerHTML = n[0];

setInterval(function() {
  p.innerHTML = n[x];
  x = ++x === n.length ? 0 : x;
}, 2000);
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: thx but I don't want it to add* the numbers, suppose the first number is 91 and the second number 167 and third 57... I know it was my bad that I didn't mention it..

Comment: @jafarjafari Ok I have edited my post to do that.

Comment: thx, much appreciated :D

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a library to handle this. 
if you do not need anything heavy you can use this: 
https://preactjs.com/

the examples on the site is pretty stepforward.

Answer (score 0):

you can do sth like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="p">1</p>
  <script>
    const element = document.getElementById('p')
    const updateNumber = () => {
      element.innerText = ((Number(element.innerText))%3)+1
    };
    setInterval(updateNumber,2000)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pretty helpful, but my numbers are in decimal and  I don't want them to be added to each other, I should have said it in the question. So imagine the first number is 91.157 and the second number 617.21...